# database(s) always in recovery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a PC which acts as a basic server runing sql server 2005. I recently noticed that some databases are in recovery for a while after I restart the PC. I suppose there may be some issues with my hard drive so I run chkdsk:

chkdsk d: \F

I still have the same problem. Is there anything else I can do? Thanks in advance!

Christian

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server database in recovery: How to stop, Take ofline or delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471830/sql-server-database-in-recovery-how-to-stop-take-ofline-or-delete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let it finish recovering if you want the database to be usable and in a consistent state.

It will always do this on start up if it is interrupted. Note: the cause is usually when SQL Server shuts down during a rollback operation.

So, let it finish and it shouldn't happen again.

*If* you are too impatient, delete the MDF/LDF when SQL Server is stopped. On restart the DB will be "suspect" and restore from backup.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4471830/27535

Answer (score 0):

recovery can take a few hours and it usually related to hard drive problem

Comment: Is there anything like (chkdsk) mitigate potential potential hard drive problems? I know that's not really related to sql server but maybe someone had similar problems? Thanks.

Comment: I had this problem when the DB was on removable disk and the sql start before the hard drive was available

Comment: Nothing to do with a disk problem: the DB would be "suspect"